# Centura Gupta (SQLBase) does not generate logfiles on windows 8.1

Tags: database, sybase, sqlbase

I've ran into an issue at my work with Centura Gupta stuff. The issue is that centura does not generate the log files for sybase database accesses (sql logs) when I do some db accesses from the company's application (also the company program is quite ancient, but that isn't the troublemaker). I have declared in the sql.ini file that log files should be generated or appended at C:\sybase.log but it does plainly nothing, no matter what I do with the application. I am willing also to provide more info about this, but I don't know to what file it logs errors or stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the application with administrator privileges and it should work